# Remove Escape Sequence from Python String

Tags: python, escaping

I'm working on a simple function that generates a random password for a new user and sends it to them via email. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import string
import random

def create_temporary_password():
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
    return "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(RANDOM_PW_LENGTH))

def main():
    temp_password = create_temporary_password()
    my_send_email_function(
        to='example@123.com',
        subject='Your Password',
        body="Your temporary password is {temp_password}"
    )
```

(There's a lot more to it than this, I've taken out the nonessentials)

Is there an easy way to ensure that temp_password doesn't by chance end up with \n or a similar escape sequence which could screw up the way the password is formatted when sent via email?

Comment: You are choosing characters from `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_\`{|}~0123456789` . There's no `\n` in there why are you worried about it?

Comment: @Mark both n and \ are located in the list of character options, so if the random module happens to put a \ followed by an n, that's my concern.

Comment: You'll probably just have to remove `\\` from the character set.

Comment: It's simplest just to remove any escape characters (e.g. `'\'`) from the character set, rather than trying to anticipate what escape sequences might be recognized today and in the future.

Comment: @AndrewMitchell you do realize that there is a difference between a literal '\' character vs the escape version?  A password can be generated as "\n\n\n" which when repr'd it would take the form of `"\\n\\n\\n"` or `r'\n\n\n'`. Try running `print(''.join(random.choice(r'\n') for _ in range(10)))`.  As for formatting issues, you may encounter issues with including the characters `<` and `>` as these form valid tags and if your end users' email clients somehow interpret them as HTML tags then that will in fact trigger your dreaded formatting issue.

Comment: Solution is simply just use ascii_letters and digits, and not include anything else problematic and make the initial password length a bit longer.

Comment: @AndrewMitchell a "\" (ascii 92) character followed by an "n" (ascii 110) is not a newline character:  "\n" (ascii 10). A new line is a is a single, distinct character.

Comment: Thanks, all! I didn't realize there was a difference between the \n as one character, and the combination of \ and n as separate characters.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `string.replace` method:

```python
password = "".join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(RANDOM_PW_LENGTH))
return password.replace('\n', '')
```

This will replace all occurrences of '\n' in the password.

If you'd like to remove other special chars from the string, you could create a list with the ones you wish to remove, and loop the code above selecting one special char at once, or even easier, you could just remove all occurrences of '\' from the string.

Comment: `'\n'` will never exist in password because it is not in `characters`.

Comment: Could you please explain why? I just tried the code and special chars were in ```characters```

Comment: A string with a "\" next to "n" is not the same as a string containing the *single newline character* "\n". They are only choosing from "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~0123456789" which does not include the new line or any other escaped-sequence characters. You can't assemble a newline character (at least not easily) out of these.